# Linq query with select needed to get specific properties from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query of which contains a List within a list.  I thought I only wanted to have First record so I had the select part of my query written like this:

```
select new
{
     EtchVectors = vio.Shapes.FirstOrDefault().Formatted
}).ToList();
```

This works great, it returns first record and the list that I have aliased "vio" has a list in it ( public List Shapes { get; set; }   and Parse contains 2 properties,  Formatted and Original.  As I am rewriting this it seems I do not have access to "Formatted" if I get rid of FirstOrDefault()

This returns BOTH Formatted and Original obviously

```
EtchVectors = vio.Shapes
```

but, I cannot obviously do this:

```
EtchVectors = vio.Shapes().Formatted  ( Shapes cannot be used like a method)
```

Should I be doing a different method or using a lambda ??

Comment: Do you need to return a list of Formatted properties of all your Shapes? You can do `EtchVectors = vio.Shapes.Select(shape=>shape.Formatted).ToList()`

Comment: Do you want to call FirstOrDefault once but return both properties: Formatted and Original?

Comment: Sorry, I was AFK ... below is what I tried and that is what i wanted, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a projection

```
EtchVectors = vio.Shapes.Select( s => s.Formatted );
```